# Вставить текст в готовый docx файл

Tags: php

Есть готовый .docx файл, (договор), в который нужно в определенные места подставить текстовые данные.

Каким образом это можно сделать на php?

Comment: [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord)

Comment: @StereoFlo пример может быть есть как это сделать с помощью PHPWord ? чтобы мог вставлять текст в определенные места в файле

Comment: как то так, см. ответ ниже

Comment: В определенном месте создаете MergeField и с помощью PhpWord вставляете что нужно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord):

```
$templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor('path/to/doc/test.docx'));
$templateProcessor->setValue(['{{test}}'], ['test']);
$templateProcessor->saveAs($fileName);
```

Comment: а как вставить текст в определенное место? Не совсем понял...

Comment: достаточно предположить, что если вы создадите файл __path/to/doc/test.docx__, в нем укажите тэг {{test}}, далее запустите php скрипт, описанный выше, то тег будет заменен на слово test, в результате.

Comment: то есть просто в нужное место через редактор ворд вставить тег {{test}} и скрипт заменит этот тег на нужный мне текст. правильно я понял?

Comment: именно! Создайте пустой word файл, вставьте тег и проверьте.

Comment: почему то ошибка в первой же строке `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' ` не подскажете в чем дело может быть?

Comment: подксажу. у вас код не правильный =) смотрите внимательно синтаксис того, что написали

Comment: почему то не могу выполнить этот скрипт. его нужно как-то устанавливать? скачал с гитхаба, но там нет файла autoload.php

Comment: Читайте, что такое composer